# C# как конвертировать большое hex число/строку в double?

Tags: c#

Используем 2 Framework.
Нету класса `biginteger`. 
Нет возможности обновить Framework.

Есть большая строка в `HEX`:

> 00aa16413cdedc4c00c0

Как на C# это преобразовать в `double`?
Если сначала преобразовывать в `int64` то происходит ошибка переполнения.

Должно получиться

> -8.0

Comment: а вам что именно нужно? Точное значение вы не получите. Думаю есть смысл использовать какой-нибудь аналог `biginteger` возможно даже самому написать...

Comment: Почему это точное не получим?!?!

Comment: ну значащих цифр в double не сильно больше чем в int64 (если не меньше, точной спецификации не помню).

Comment: и кстати почему -8? А не 1603629870196981952 к примеру?

Comment: Потому что потому что) это известно точно и без вариантов. Это начальное время из файла. Я вижу его через работающую программу с этим файлом. Мне надо написать свою

Comment: время отрицательное O_O. Вы граничные условия добавьте. Если время, то принято делить на секунды и микросекунды и хранить 2 целыми числами и так далее. И как получить -8 я лично не понимаю...

Comment: Почему нету? UInt64

Comment: При преобразовании в десятичное число у меня получилось *3137550122400820756672*. Но не *-8*.

Comment: данная строка в HEX формата string ?

Comment: если да, то берёте и ручками (свой код пишите) переводите число из HEX в DEC, а так же регулярно берёте модуль по 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 и по логике вещей вы получите -8 в конце, а потом, -8 в double

Comment: Похоже на Little-endian 80-битное число с плавающей запятой (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision).